# React Native Teleport components without loosing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, portal, react-native-video

I am using React Native 0.62 with [react-native-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video).

I need to add a video player with full screen option. The requirements specifically needs custom controls in both normal view and full screen. The native full screen in IOS doesn't allow custom controls, therefore I have developed a in house solution for a full screen video by showing it inside a modal. Here the problem starts...

When moving the component from normal view to full screen inside a modal, it looses all its internal reference and state. I was able to recover most of it (like progress and play/pause state) by taking those outside the player. However i am still loosing all the video caching and buffering, and the video reloads again.

Can anyone suggest a way I can move a component in DOM without loosing its internal state?

Things I have tried so far:

- Providing key to component
- UseContext to render the player in the parent and use a wrapperComponent to have the modal around it.
- Looked into portal, but couldn't find any possible solution for this problem.